# C Function pointer, differentiable function

Tags: c, function, pointers

Write a function deriv that approximately computes the derivative f'(x) of a real valued,
differentiable function f : R → R at a fixed point x ∈ R by building the difference quotient
(f(x + h) − f(x))/h
for sufficiently small h > 0. The function f shall be transferred by a function pointer
parameter fun and x is simply given by a double-parameter x. Add your function to the
following program and complete it:

```
1 #include <stdio.h>
2 ...... deriv(........................){
3 ...........
4 }
5 double quad(double x){return(x*x);}
6 double cube(double x){return(x*x*x);}
7 double inv(double x){return((x!=0)?1/x:0);}
8
9 int main(void){
10 double x;
11 printf("x = "); scanf("%lf",&x);
12 printf("(x^2)’ = %lf \n",............);
13 printf("(x^3)’ = %lf \n",............);
14 printf("(1/x)’ = %lf \n",............);
15 return 0;
16 }
```

I dont really know how to approach this, so far I only have (chose h=0.1) :

```
1 #include <stdio.h>
2 double deriv(........................){
3 (f(x+0.1)-fx)/0.1
4 }
5 double quad(double x){return(x*x);}
6 double cube(double x){return(x*x*x);}
7 double inv(double x){return((x!=0)?1/x:0);}
8
9 int main(void){
10 double x;
11 double (*fun) (double);
12 printf("x = "); scanf("%lf",&x);
13 printf("(x^2)’ = %lf \n",............);
14 printf("(x^3)’ = %lf \n",............);
15 printf("(1/x)’ = %lf \n",............);
16 return 0;
17}
```

I would manage to give fx to the function deriv, but somehow have to give f(x+h) aswell to deriv?

Comment: Can you remove the line numbers?

Comment: When creating a [mcve] please don't include line-numbers. A good [mcve] would be copy-able by us to test and replicate the problems you have, and for that we should need to do as little modifications as possible to make it work.

Comment: Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You have to pass a function pointer and a value `x`. The value `h` is an implementation defined number, that you can for example `#define` at the beginning of the program. In general, a smaller _h_ yields a more exact result, but beware of rounding errors.

Comment: You should be using `nextafter()` and/or `nextbefore()` rather than using a fixed value, otherwise you'll end up getting 0 for the derivative of all functions as _x_/_h_ exceeds the precision of `double`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double f(double x) { return x * x; }

double df(double (*my_f)(double), double x, double h)
{
  return (my_f(x + h) - my_f(x)) / h;
}

int main()
{
  double x = 3, h = 1e-6;

  printf("Test f= %f, df= %f", f(x), df(f, x, h));

  return 0;
}
```

that prints (f(x) = x*x, df(x) = 2*x, thus f(3) = 3*3 = 9, df(3) = 2*3 = 6)

> `Test f= 9.000000, df= 6.000001`

The important part is the way you can pass a function to another function, that is:

```
double df(double (*my_f)(double), double x, double h) { ... }
```

where you pass to the `df` function a function pointer `my_f` that points on a function having a double as argument and returning a double.

---

**Update:**

Here is another example, that maybe can help you to understand what a function pointer is:

```
double g(float x1, float x2)
{
  return x1/x2; 
}

int main()
{

  typedef double(*g_type)(float,float); // the function pointer type
                                        // (it defines function 
                                        //  arguments and return types)

  g_type my_g = g; // my_g is a pointer of type g_type,
                   // fed with g function memory address

  printf("Test g= %f", my_g(1,2)); // uses my_g (here call the g function)

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, i think i understand. But don't you have to declare your pointer somewhere before using it?

Comment: @vincent.perl99 actually you don't need to declare a pointer. It's like if you have `int test;`and then use a pointer by taking the adress `&test`. But for a function pointer you don't have to write `&function`

Comment: @vincent.perl99 I have modified the name `f` to `my_f` to avoid any ambiguity. No, you do not need any extra declaration.  `my_f` type is a pointer on a function taking a double as argument and returning a double. In C a function name, like f or g is simply a pointer: the adresse of the function. See my "update", for another example. Is it ok now?

Answer (score 2):

So this is my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 double deriv (double (*fun)(double), double x, double h)
 {
     return (fun(x + h) - fun(x)) / h;
 }

double quad(double x){return(x*x);}
double cube(double x){return(x*x*x);}
double inv(double x){return((x!=0)?1/x:0);}

int main(void)
{
     double x;
     double h=0.00001;
     printf("x = "); scanf("%lf",&x);
     printf("(x^2)’ = %lf \n",deriv(quad,x,h));
     printf("(x^3)’ = %lf \n",deriv(cube,x,h));
     printf("(1/x)’ = %lf \n",deriv(inv,x,h));
     return 0;
}
```